# Caching images in memory on iOS, what is smaller : a UIImage or NSData object?

Tags: ios, memory, uiimage, nsdata

I'm working on an image cache on iOS. Images are downloaded from URL and stored in a NSDictionary as a UIImage (I don't want or need "on disk" cache).

The question is : should I store images in my dictionary as UIImage or NSData ? Which one is significantly smaller in term of memory ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSData is smaller because it stores the compressed version of the image. But [decompressing takes time](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/), so as long as memory allows, cache the UIImage and clean the cache if you get a memory warning.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. Once it is done, I get a second and sometimes a third warning a bit later. Then the app crashes. Maybe I'm not looking into the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

`UIImage` has optimizations for automatically responding to low memory situations and releasing its cached representations. From the [UIImage reference:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> In low-memory situations, image data may be purged from a UIImage object to free up memory on the system. This purging behavior affects only the image data stored internally by the UIImage object and not the object itself. When you attempt to draw an image whose data has been purged, the image object automatically reloads the data from its original file. This extra load step, however, may incur a small performance penalty.

Generally speaking you should leave image data in a `UIImage`.

If images are something you can re-fetch as needed, you should consider [NSPurgeableData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPurgeableData_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or your own  objects, together with an [NSCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) rather than an `NSDictionary`. `NSCache` is particularly nice memory stored in it can be automatically released by the OS, even while you are suspended, avoiding you being terminated while in the background. `UIImage` does a lot of this for you already, but `NSCache` would allow you to free all the data rather than just the uncompressed data.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that NSCache is only available in iOS 4.0 and later

Comment: Unfortunately, UIImage optimization you are talking about does not apply to UIImage loaded from a server.

Comment: @David, while data-loaded UIImages can't purge the underlying data the way `imageNamed:` does, they can purge their decoded representations and still free up significant memory.

Comment: @RobNapier NSPurgeableData is not about caching; only NSCache is. It's manages object memory by ensuring there is only one instance of its data. You lock it (beginContentAccess) so it can't be referenced or created elsewhere, and then unlock it (endContentAccess) for use elsewhere, and/or flag it for purging (discardContentIfPossible). Because UIImage already implements the NSDiscardableContent protocol, the underlying data of an UIImage created from that data will be purged when you purge the NSPurgeableData object. For any other class, you must implement the protocol manually.